# Помогите спроектировать Activity в Android приложении

Tags: android, activity

Задача: написать приложение с активити, которое меняет своё содержимое. Пример беру с приложения VK, где при выборе элемента меню слева (Друзья, Сообщения, Новости etc) содержимое основного активити меняется в соответствии с выбранным элементом.

Интересует, с помощью чего это реализовано. Пытался копать в сторону разных фрагментов и замены их друг другом, но не смог сформулировать вопрос поисковикам так, чтобы получить вразумительный ответ.

Собственно, суть вопроса: продолжать попытки сделать всё подменой нужных фрагментов (и является ли это вообще нормальным решением) или, может быть, правильно будет переподгружать лэйауты (или использовать какое-нибудь более удобное и менее "костыльное" решение)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно - через замену фрагментов. То, что вы описали - это стандартный паттерн от гугла. **NavigationDrawer** называется. Его просто нагуглить и в Eclipse и в AndroidStudio есть готовые шаблоны.

**UPD_0:**

Да, вместо смены фрагментов можно инфлэйтить другие лэйауты. Но, ИМХО, это менее удобно, чем использовать фрагменты.

1) Во-первых, в фрагментах используется как раз таки метод **inflate** для загрузки разметки.

2) К тому же у них есть жизненный цикл, а значит можно именно в них ловить события свёртывания приложения, например, и сохранять данные.

3) Используя FragmentManager можно легко настроить обратную навигацию по списку открытых фрагментов. Т.е. открываете по очереди 10 разных фрагментов и всего парой строк кода можете нажимая кнопку **назад** вернуться обратно по списку.

4) Так лучше модульность кода получается. Можно переиспользовать фрагменты в разных местах со всем их поведением.

Итого, на мой взгляд, подход с фрагментами гибче и правильней.

Comment: Кстати, по [этой](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer#alternative-to-fragments) ссылке нашёл альтернативу фрагментам - инфлэйт разных лэйаутов по переключению. Хотелось бы знать плюсы и минусы обоих способов, чтобы заранее оценить, с чем придётся столкнуться. Мне лично больше хотелось бы реализовать через инфлэйт, но раз уж гугл рекомендует в паттерне использовать фрагменты, то я сомневаюсь, что выбрать.

Comment: @Kotenko, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос достаточно обширный, т.к касается основ проектирования пользовательских интерфейсов.

И вариантов здесь, следовательно, много. Среди наиболее разумных можно выделить минимум два:

- Использовать правильно спроектированные фрагменты. Именно "правильно спроектированные" с точки зрения раздробленности UI, потому как часто по неопытности этим понятием пренебрегают, разбивая по фрагментам чуть-ли не каждый элемент интерфейса и "пихая" фрагменты, куда только можно. Если будете следовать этому простому правилу и размышлять, прежде чем писать код, то этот метод становится наилучшим.
- Следующий вариант - использование WebView и сопутствующих вебу технологий. Действительно, управлять HTML интерфейсом с помощью JS, наверное, самый удобный вариант для разработчиков любого ранга. Но вариант этот не слишком удобный и достаточно ресурсоемкий с точки зрения Android. Его можно отнести к разряду "костыльных". Поэтому его использование в данном случае можно посчитать уместным, если вы профильно разбираетесь в тонкостях оптимизации компонента WebView и тонкостях HTML\JS при написании разметки\кода для него.